# Different cod/jad files created using Blackberry jde and Ant

Tags: java, blackberry, ant

I am using blackberry ant tools to generate cod/jad files and found the generated cod to be different from the one i am trying to generate using blackberry JDE 5.0 .

The sizes of the siblings cod files and main cod file are not the same.
However I am able to install and run  the app using the cod files generated  from either JDE or Blackberry ant tools without any problem.

I am using the same source code and resource files in both the cases.

Can someone suggest me  what could be  reason for different cod sizes in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing sizes to compare cod files?   The cod file is a zip of other files, and those files themselves are zip files.   Since this format uses timestamps, you would not expect identical inputs to produce identical output.

Comment: Thanks for replying Michael,Can you please explain what do you mean by "this format uses timestamps" and how does using timestamps produces different sizes

Answer (score 0):

I've just found and read [this post](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/how-to-use-rapc-from-rim-dirty-details/), but can't verify his claims yet. He suggests we must be very careful with the JDE versions we use to compile the app with. Make sure to use a JDE version matching your development target OS.

I think the different JDE versions create slightly different outputs.

I haven't got my apps building correctly yet with Ant, hopefully I'll remember to revisit this answer when I do.